# JSP tag alert in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

How can I alert JSP tag inside javascript?? Is it possible? I want to alert

```
 <%=%>
```

I tried:

```
 alert("<%=%>")
```

but it is not working.

Comment: It should be possible to do this. Can you show (a piece of) the JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need escape the character:

[It is working here](http://jsfiddle.net/McDHD/)

```
alert("<%=%>")
```

Check console for errors, which blocking it to alert.

Comment: OK, now put that on a jsp page. The <%=%> bit gets interpreted as jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert("\<\%=\%\>");
```

The '\' characters escape the following character to stop them being interpreted as jsp delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
<script language="javascript">  
function one()  
{  
    alert("var: "+<%= var %> );  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
String a = "123";
%>


var v = '<%=a%>';
alert(v);
```

try it like this;